# Function and its continuous inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

I would be in need of a little help with a problem im facing. I have to show that the function

$$ f(x) = x^7 + x^²$$

defined at $f: \Bbb{R} $ $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb{R}$ has a continuous inverse function $g: \Bbb{R} $ $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb{R}$

How would this go? Finding the inverse of the particular function showed out to be relatively tricky to find.

Comment: Instead of trying to find an inverse function, just show that there can exist one. Can you think of conditions for the existence?

Comment: Note that $ f(0) =f(-1) =0$ and so $f$ is not one to one.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a function $f$ to have an inverse $f^{-1}$ is being bijective, which means being 1-1 and onto. We need to check whether the function you gave is bijective, so we can simply graph it:

[image: graph of a function]

As you can see, $f(x)=x^7+x^2$ is not 1-1, as it does not meet the definition:
$$f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a = b$$
which means that $f$ does not have an inverse function.

Comment: So is the case so that a function only has an inverse function if it's bijective?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the definitions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions), but the main thing you should take a look at is "To be invertible, a function must be both an injection and a surjection. Such functions are called bijections.".